# Js substring doesn't work on react fetched string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel

I've couldn't find answer on google so I though you guys might help me out.

So I've tried componentWillMount(), componentDidMount() but it appears substring method gets called before I received fetched string.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";

class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            reminders: [{}],
            test: "test"
        };
    }

    getReminders(){
        fetch('/api/reminder/',{method:"GET"}).then(resp => resp.json()).then(data => 
            this.setState({reminders:data}));
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        this.getReminders();
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="main-table">
                { this.state.reminders.map((x,i) => 
                <div key={i} className="table-item">
                    <div className="item-name">{x.title}</div>
                    <div className="item-content flex">
                        <div className="time">{x.from.substr(11,2)} - {x.to}</div>
                        <div className="location">{x.location}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>) }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: Initialize your `reminders` array to an empty array instead of an array with an empty object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the empty object out of `reminders` in `state` so the array has no initial length

That is giving the array a length of `1` to start with and the properties you are looking for inside `map()` don't exist on that specific object

```
    this.state = {
        reminders: [],
        test: "test"
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you initialize  `this.state.reminders` with not empty array, but with array with empty object, which caused err when you are accessing it props
You can either initialize with empty array, e.g.

```
this.state = {
        reminders: []
}
```

Or you can add some property, e.g. `isRemindersLoaded` which initially set to false, and only render table after it has been set to true, e.g:

```
this.setState({reminders:data, isRemindersLoaded: true}));
```